# Sublime Text: Why regex in syntax highlighting does not work?

Tags: php, regex, syntax-highlighting, sublime-text-3

In Sublime Text 3, a default syntax highlighting rule paints a SQL `SELECT` just fine if it's in the same line, but not if it's in the next line:

[image: single-line sql string]
vs
[image: multiline sql string]

After reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18067781/change-add-syntax-highlighting-for-a-language-in-sublime-2-3) I opened the PHP package (this is a php project) and looked at the syntax rules (PHP.tmLanguage):

```xml
<dict>
    <key>begin</key>
    <string>"\s*(?=(SELECT|INSERT|UPDATE|DELETE|CREATE|REPLACE|ALTER)\b)</string>
    <key>beginCaptures</key>
    <dict>
        <key>0</key>
        <dict>
            <key>name</key>
            <string>punctuation.definition.string.begin.php</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

As far as I could tell that regex is correct, but I still [tested it in regex101](https://regex101.com/r/jG7fH2/1). It does capture the `SELECT` just fine there, so I don't think there is any problem with the actual regex.

Any idea how to make the syntax highlighted on multiple line SQL strings?

Comment: My best guess: `\s` isn't selecting newlines, and `[\s\r\n]` needs to specified. Alternatively, there's some override on newlines elsewhere. I'm not super familiar with Sublime Text, but hopefully this is a bit helpful.

Comment: Okay, I just installed Sublime Text and looked at the syntax highlighting for the PHP example you provided, and it highlighted the `SELECT` whether or not there was an indent after the opening quotation mark. I also don't know where you got the `PHP.tmLanguage`; I looked at the syntax in `PHP.sublime-package`, and don't currently have a file called `PHP.tmLanguage` on my computer.

Comment: @Graham My initial problem was not with an indent, but with a line break. Also, I asked that question on July 13th 2015, I guess quite a lot has changed in Sublime in the last 3 years. But please feel free to try with a line break, not an indent. Disclaimer: I dont use Sublime anymore

Comment: Sorry, I didn't look at the asking date carefully. Whoops. I also meant line break instead of indent.